# How to open the windows without ignition turned on

Tags: electronics, power-windows

Car: Skoda Octavia y.99

Situation: I need to be able to open the windows (or atleast one window) on my Skoda without ignition on.

Why: My car is a camper and it's super anoying to turn the ignition on all the time

What I've tried:
On car's with switches directly controlling motors it's easy-you only bring stable fused 12v to main switch and you have the system alive even without ignition on.

On VAG concern cars, the motors are permanently connected to the power and electronic signal open them or close.

My idea: let the comfort unit think that the ignition is switched on, so it will leave the windows alive

But I don't know how to achieve it.

Does anybody done that?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: If you have a key remote, then holding down (10 secs or more) the open or unlock button will open the windows - on many cars. Also holding lock will close windows left open.

Comment: The Octavia will open/close all door windows with the key fob as mentioned, after a couple of seconds. If you want to open/close them only a little, release the button when they begin to move. If the engine has been switched off and the key is still in the ignition, the actual window switches will function. But why, dear software engineer, do you cancel that when a door is opened?

Comment: Unfortunately guys, none of these will work. It's an old Octavia without any proper can-bus so the options are very limited